# Windows 10 - Fonts garbled in two applications

Tags: windows-10, fonts

I am having an issue with text displaying wrongly in a couple of applications I use. Both are from the same manufacturer. This has only started happening in the last few days. I can't pinpoint anything specific that I might have installed that would cause this issue

If I copy the garbled text from this app and paste it into Notepad or Firefox etc it displays correctly in an English font, so it seems that the font may be corrupted, or using the wrong language?

I have tried rebuilding the font cache, reset region settings (though I don't use multiple languages), re-installing the effected applications, several virus scans and been in touch with the manufacturer, who haven't seen anything like this before. I'm starting to fear the only solution is to reinstall Windows, which I really want to avoid if possible. I have tried a system restore but it wasn't "old" enough to solve the problem.

Does anyone have any other suggestions that I could try?

Garbled text example :

[image]

Comment: In the last few days, have you installed or updated any new application or font?

Comment: I updated one piece of software, but the system restore point I used rolled back to before this

Comment: I don't think that system restore will delete added fonts. Check folder `C:\Windows\Fonts` if any font files were added in the last few days. If found, see [Remove languages and fonts you don't use](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/remove-languages-and-fonts-you-don-t-use-0915efdf-3eec-4e87-8b2f-ba0d47242ea6), and let me know.

Comment: Finally found the issue - there were some corrupted Segoe fonts in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts. I booted into safe mode, re-installed the Segoe fonts then deleted the contents of that folder. This has pretty much solved the problem, although now the "open" option in the right click context menu is corrupted. Incidentally, I couldn't find a way to view fonts by date in C:\Windows\Fonts?